# @Input() value in @Hostlistener method always 'undefined'

Tags: angular

I need to use value from `@Input()` in my `@Hostlistener` method, but this value undefined what's wrong?

```
export class InputHelpComponent implements OnInit {
  isOpened: boolean = false;
  @Input() field!: string;

  @HostListener("mouseenter", ['$event']) onMouseEnter(event: Event) {
    console.log('hostlistener:', this.field); // 'undefined'

    //some code using this.field

    this.isOpened = true;
  }
}
```

may be add additional variable and make an assigment in `ngOnInt` for example?

Comment: Probably the issue is with the way you passing the [field] input value.

Comment: i solve this problem!) -  i have several child comp in parent and i checked child component without [field]! o.O

Answer (score 0):

I can't see how you're passing the input to the component. Please check how you passed the input 'field' to InputHelpComponent.
'field' is supposed to be a string. For instance, the following will make always 'field' undefined.

```
<app-input-help [field]="this is a test"></app-input-help>
console.log(this.field) // undefined
```

You need to pass the value this way:

```
<app-input-help [field]="'this is a test'"></app-input-help>
```

Comment: i solve this problem!) - i have several child comp in parent and i checked child component without [field]! o.O